# A simple credentials table for mySQL

Tags: c++, mysql

Here is my simple table definition for a mysql credentials table.

```
  case "credentials":
    self::create('credentials', 'identifier INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, flname VARCHAR(60), email VARCHAR(32), pass VARCHAR(40), PRIMARY KEY(identifier)');
    break;
```

Please ignore all but the inner arguments...the syntax is good...I just want to verify the form.  Basically, I have an auto-incrementing int for the PRIMARY KEY and 3 fields - the users's name, email, and password.

I want this to be as simple as possible.  Searches will be based upon the id

Question: Will this work for a basic credentials table?

Answer (score 1):

Please please please do not store passwords in plaintext.

Use a well known iterated hashing function, such as bcrypt or PBKDF2. Don't store a raw MD5 hash, or even a raw SHA or SHA-2 hash. You should always salt and iterate your hashes to be secure.

You'll need one extra column to store the salt, and if you want to be flexible you could also have per-user iteration counts and maybe even per-user hash functions. That gives you the flexibility to change to a different hash function in the future without requiring all users to immediately change their passwords.

Apart from that the table looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you increase the size of the email field (maximum length of an email can be up to 256 chars). Also you should store your passwords as a hash (e.g. bcrypt) not a plain string.